# Is multithreading an answer to performance improvement for an application

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have a console application which does the following:

1. Reads an input file. The input file has row-wise data running into thousands of rows
2. Pre-process the input file and convert into an intermediate file. The intermediate file has an equal number of rows.
3. Reads one row from the intermediate file at a time, forms a web request and sends it to a webserver.
4. Reads the response from the webserver for each request at a time, process(parse) it and write it to an output file. The output also has an equal number of rows as the input file.

Now, currently the application works fine, but it is very slow. I want to improve the performance of the application so as to make it bit faster.

1. Can someone tell me about various approaches that may be used in this case?
2. If multithreading is the answer to the problem, can someone suggest few starting pointers?

Edit:
All the requests are going to the same server. As far as the sever is concerned, I have very little or no knowledge about its tolerance (if it comes down to this, I may look to limit the numbers of request threads to the server).

Comment: Are all the requests going to the same webserver? How well does that server scale to handling several parallel requests?

Comment: All the requests are going to the same server. As far as the sever is concerned, I have very little or no knowledge about its tolerance.

Comment: @futurenext110 it seems to me you need to *find that out* in order to give a qualified/informed answer to this...

Comment: I would also consider batching the web requests. Based on the limited amount of info in the question, my guess is that serial latency is your biggest bottleneck, but profile first.

Comment: Alright. But for now it will be a valid assumption: not to worry about the server capability of handling several parallel requests.

Comment: @Tim, could you please expand on your answer.

Comment: Essentially, if you are sending one request at a time and not threading anything, you are stacking a lot of latency back to back. Thus, threading is definitely worth investigation, but you might also investigate sending more than one record per request. So instead of 1000 tiny requests, 10 batches of 100. This assumes that the server can process more than one record per request.

Comment: @futurenext110 Did you profile your application to get an idea what's the bottleneck with the greatest impact? For me, it's a bit difficuilt to give a suggestion without knowing anything about the runtime behavior.

Comment: You have to measure things to find out where your bottleneck is. If, for example, your bottleneck is network latency, then parallising requests is going to reduce the overall amount of time it takes, but you might actually find that *batching* (say sending 20 at once) requests is equally effective. I suspect that all you will find to begin with is that you'll be moving the bottleneck...

Answer (score 2):

#### To thread or not to thread? That is the question...

A simple and correct answer to the multithreading part of the question is: yes, as soon as 1) it is feasible according to the algorithm and 2) it either involves I/O-bound ops or you have several cores in CPU-bound ops

#### First point: feasibility

1. In order to perform step 2 you must complete step 1. No multithreading yet
2. Step 3 requires completion of step 2, **but** involves independent by-row activities (one request per row). BINGO!!
3. Step 4 requires completion of all requests at step 3. Multithreading ends there.

#### Second point: type of operation

A web request isan I/O-bound op. You get maximum benefit. Since you are performing requests to the same server, fault tolerant or not, you must limit your query rate. A proper *tuning* of the number of concurrent request is required, but if you use constants in the code (like `const int NUMBER_OF_THREADS = 4;`) you have a good starting point.

#### The proposal

*Use semaphores to handle concurrent requests.*

Start your program by reading file and converting to intermediate file, as you did before.

Once finished, create an array of fixed size (you said the final file has the same number of rows, so you can allocate it), then start a loop for each row:

1. Acquire a semaphore that is initialized at `NUMBER_OF_THREADS` constant, this will allow the main thread to activate 4 concurrent threads
2. Start a thread by passing it the row, the target array and the index (you don't actually need to pass all of them as parameters, i.e. if the lists are class members)

After the loop, wait on an `AutoResetEvent` that I'm going to discuss briefly

In the threads, do the following:

1. Perform the web request
2. Process result
3. Save the result to the corresponding target array row
4. Increment a variable that is **shared across threads** (not discussed here) with `Interlocked.Increment()` method
5. `if` the shared variable `equals` the number of rows, `then` release the `AutoResetEvent` I mentioned so you'll unlock main thread

#### Tuning

Start with 4 concurrent threads. Try to increase them to 8 and see performance. I suggest you don't go over 12 threads, but others here could say that might be too much... It's just try-and-fail.

Answer (score 0):

While reading the file, you're also writing files. The first thing that comes to mind for is to read the file in large blocks (BufferedReader) to ensure that your disk doesn't seek too much.

As for your server, in my experience most web servers are quite tolerant against multiple requests per second. If you host the server for yourself, I would simply use async web requests and figure out what happens... However, from the sounds of it you are creating a simple web crawler, in which case I strongly recommend being patient: causing trouble on someone else's server is not a good idea, ever. To give you an indication: our web crawlers always were limited to 1 request per second per server.

Answer (score 0):

I would create an aplication based on internal message queues and a producer-consumer chain.

`* -> * -> * -> *`

where each `*` is a thread doing: reads, processing, querying WS, post-processing. A `*` node sleeps when it's produce queue is full or consume queue is empty.

If need be, you can make several consumers at each point (most probably in WS handler), like this:

```
         / * \ 
* -> * ->  *  -> *
         \ * /
```

After the architecture is ready, you can tweak the app by changing sizes of queues at each point.

Moreover - you can use a thread pool to handle each processing node, therefore making sure that the most is used of your processor.